# Not receiving a refresh token from Google when using Asp.Net Core Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, google-openid

I have an Asp.Net Core application with Identity Server 4. The application is using Google for authentication. Everything works fine except that I can't get the refresh token from Google.

I'm using the following code when adding authentication with Google.

```
.AddAuthentication()
.AddGoogle("Google", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    options.ClientId = googleLoginProvider.ClientId;
    options.ClientSecret = googleLoginProvider.ClientSecret;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.AccessType = "offline";
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = string.Concat(options.AuthorizationEndpoint, "?prompt=select_account");
    if (googleLoginProvider.Scopes != null)
    {
        foreach (var scope in googleLoginProvider.Scopes)
        {
            options.Scope.Add(scope);
        }
    }
});
```

I use the following code to get the tokens

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme, "access_token");
var refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme, "refresh_token ");
```

The access token is correct but the refresh token is null.

**UPDATE: This setup was correct except for a trailing whitespace after the refresh_token**

The correct code should be

```
var refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme, "refresh_token");
```

Comment: If I take the code that I get from Google, then I can exchange it for both access and refresh token using the https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token endpoint, hence it must be something wrong with how Asp.Net core retrieves or stores the refresh token.

Comment: did you solve this problem? I have the same problem, except I only get this issue in release configuration, it works as expected in debug.